# TFS build process template for Database project

Tags: tfs

I am trying to have a server build for my db project and I am following how it is done in below link,

http://www.mytechfinds.com/articles/software-testing/6-test-automation/64-db-deployment-tfs

though tere are certain pieces not clear to me like how to get the "Workspace" variable  for ConvertWorkspaceItem ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like overkill, from what is described in the blog, he's passing the path of the dbproj to msbuild and then calling the "deploy" target.

You could do the same thing by adding the project to "items to build" in the default template (change the "Items of Type" to *.*.proj) and then in the under advanced pass in /t:deploy as an MSbuild argument